# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Landroid/os/PowerManager$HtcCpuCtrl$1;.<init>

Tags: java, android, nosuchmethoderror

had look this link  [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html][1] , I even do not know the error occur. Anybody knows.

Note: this error happend on HTC609d phone, and not crash always.

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Landroid/os/PowerManager$HtcCpuCtrl$1;.<init>
at android.os.PowerManager$HtcCpuCtrl.<init>(PowerManager.java:972)
at android.os.PowerManager.newHtcCpuCtrl(PowerManager.java:1280)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onAttachedToWindow(AbsListView.java:2859)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:11895)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2428)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2435)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2435)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2435)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3443)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3275)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3220)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3196)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:958)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow(FragmentTabHost.java:283)
at com.sangfor.pocket.uin.main.MoaFragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow(MoaFragmentTabHost.java:34)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:11895)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2428)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2435)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2435)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2435)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2435)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2435)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2435)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2435)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2435)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1469)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1236)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4750)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:746)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:572)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:538)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:731)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

This **NoSuchMethodError** means, well, that there is no such method ;-)

In this case, I guess that on the device you are running your program *android.os.PowerManger* package doesn't provide **HtcCpuCtrl** class.

Just checked sources for API 22 and there is no such thing like HtcCpuCtrl.
It's not listed in PowerManger documentation as well:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

Guessing from the name, sounds like it's somehing HTC specific...

Comment: It wouldn't be listed, since it's not part of the public API.

Comment: it's not in PowerManager.java file as well so at the end it's not available on a device your are running your code. my bet it's HTC-only thing ...
and when run on non-HTC device you end up with NoSuchMethodError exception.

Comment: we develop a application , not use HtcCpuCtrl  class directly, I think PowerManager call HtcCpuCtrl only on HTC device. and it only relative to that phone api. I think the phone api have HtcCpuCtrl class, otherwise , application will alway crash

Comment: @pelotasplus google Standard api have not HtcCpuCtrl, this error only happend on Htc device

Comment: googled a bit and found this:

https://github.com/hallovveen31/M8_android.policy_mods/blob/master/smali/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindowManager$2.smali

still, it's HTC-only internal stuff that somehow doesn't work on this device :-/ no idea how can you "fix" your app to not to trigger this behaviour ...